# Getting errors when running npm run dev

Tags: npm

When I run `npm run dev` in my server, I get a bunch of errors and then it says that the complete log can be found in .npm.

I checkout the log, but I'm still not sure as to why I'm getting errors. One of the reasons why I'm not sure as to what is going on
is because if I run `npm run dev` on my local machine, it works fine.

error log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'dev' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.5
3 info using node@v12.18.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle @~predev: @
6 info lifecycle @~dev: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~dev: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:{{ path_to_file }}/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle @~dev: CWD: {{ path_to_file }}
10 silly lifecycle @~dev: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run development' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: @ dev: `npm run development`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd {{ path_to_file }}
16 verbose Linux 5.3.0-1032-azure
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v12.18.2
19 verbose npm  v6.14.5
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ dev: `npm run development`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

my package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "laravel-mix-merge-manifest": "^0.1.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "algoliasearch": "^4.5.1",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "instantsearch.css": "^7.4.5",
        "vue-bootstrap-typeahead": "^0.2.6",
        "vue-instantsearch": "^3.2.0",
        "vue-router": "^3.4.3",
        "vue-server-renderer": "^2.6.12",
        "vue-simple-suggest": "^1.10.2",
        "vuetify": "^2.3.10",
        "webpack-merge": "^5.1.4"
    }
}
```

Comment: Add package.json here

Comment: I've added my package.json file